# How to Query .DBF that had some corrupt/broken data row

Tags: sql, database, dbf, dbase

I have some issue when query from another app db to collect data because some of that table had corrupt/broken data that sample like this

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0BUU.jpg)

that broken line in tables cannot be delete or edit because the other app will be error.

My question is how to work around with this issue? 
how to avoid query read from top and go get data from row no 4 to bottom?

Thanks,
Hendra

Comment: Use an hex editor to "repair" the record. Another solution could be write a small program (whatever programming language you like), and write 0x20 bytes from the first byte of the record to the last, but when doing ths, be careful - make this only on a copy of your file

Comment: I dont think thats a good idea, but i will try to use hex editor to repair. thanks

Comment: do you use Harbour / xHarbour? If so, you can write the program I mentioned above much simpler: somehow like: use dbf, goto record, replace all fields with the empty value for the field. And to be completely sure, DELETE the record, then RECALL it to ensure a correct value for the deleted marker (0x20) if NOT deleted